# Navigate up to different parent activity from WebView

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

In my `MainActivity` I have 5 buttons, 4 of wich open a `WebViewActivity` to display static HTML-content. The 5th button goes to `PumpsActivity` which contains additional 5 buttons that also open the `WebViewActivity` to display static HTML-pages.

#### Now to the problem:

I'd like to be able to "navigate up" from the `WebViewActivity` to the appropriate parent activity. For instance: if the `WebViewActivity` was called from `MainActivity` than navigating up should take the user to `MainActivity`. This is easy implemented following the guide on [android.developer.com](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html).
But how do I get the `WebViewActivity` to navigate up to the `PumpsActivity`? **How can I check from which activity the `WebViewActivity` was started?**

Relevant code from my `WebViewActivity` (basically the same as in the [guide](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html)):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    setTitle(intent.getStringExtra("WEBVIEW_TITLE"));

    webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvMyWebView);
    WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.loadUrl(intent.getStringExtra("WEBVIEW_URL"));
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // This is called when the Home (Up) button is pressed
            // in the Action Bar.
            Intent parentActivityIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            
            parentActivityIntent.addFlags(
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(parentActivityIntent);
            finish();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: add a parent activity type as a parameter to the Intent which starts WebView activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Leonidos suggests, you could add a parameter, but this introduces extra coupling, and I get the feeling that the parents only have the Activity superclass in common, and passing an Activity type isn't ideal.

One way that springs to mind to do it is to have another String extra in WebViewActivity which indicates the calling Activity. In onOptionsItemSelected you could then check the parent string extra to see which Activity called it, and navigate to that Activity as appropriate.

Comment: Passing a other String extra was my inital thought aswell, but since I'm new to Android dev I wasn't sure how. I tried using `getIntent()` inside `onOptionsItemSelected` and then getting the extra but that didn't seem to work. Maybe I messed something up? I'll give it another go.

Comment: try something along the lines of:
in the parent class:
    `myintent.putExtra(WebViewActivity.PARENT_EXTRA, "MainActivity")`

and in the onOptionsItemSelected: `String parent = getStringExtra(WebViewActivity.PARENT_EXTRA)`

Where WebViewActivity.PARENT_EXTRA is a final static string in WebViewActivity

Comment: This is what I ended up doing: I passed an extra String with the intent: `intent.putExtra("PARENT", "pump")` then in my `WebViewActivity` I declared a `private String strParent` and in the `onCreate` I do `strParent = intent.getStringExtra("PARENT")`. Then finally inside ònOptionsItemSelected` I check `if(strParent.equals("pump")`.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your comment :) Thanks for your help!

Comment: No worries, better that you figured it out yourself!